# beautifulsoup get all urls from a site

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

In the following i am trying to get all the hyperlinks of the site http://www.searspartsdirect.com but i get the output as ,what am i doing wrong here

```
 <html>
<body onload="document.acsForm.submit();">

    <form name="acsForm" action="https://www.searspartsdirect.com/partsdirect/j_acegi_cas_security_check?ssonofail=true" method="post">
        <div style="display: none">

            <textarea rows=10 cols=80 name="logonPassword"></textarea>

            <textarea rows=10 cols=80 name="loginId"></textarea>

            <textarea rows=10 cols=80 name="screenName"></textarea>

            <textarea rows=10 cols=80 name="errorCode"></textarea>

        </div>
      </form>
</body>
 </html>
```

this is my script:

```
  import httplib2
  import sys
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup , SoupStrainer
  import urllib , urllib2 , cookielib , random ,datetime,time,sys


  sitename=sys.argv[1]
  http = httplib2.Http()
  status, response = http.request(sitename)
  cookiejar = cookielib.CookieJar()
  urlOpener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookiejar))
  urllib2.install_opener(urlOpener)
  request = urllib2.Request(sitename)
  url = urlOpener.open(request)
  contents = url.read()
  soup = BeautifulSoup(contents)
  for a in soup.findAll('a'):
     print a
```

Comment: what do you expect the output to be? (you ARE printing the entire contents with `print contents` and the contents seems to not include any `<a>` tags... so `findAll('a')` is empty...

Comment: why not try using a regex on the site and just return all URL type strings?

Comment: @zenopy :If u notice i am also printing variable 'a' to find the hyperlinks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with BeautifulSoup - the source on the index page redirects to another URL using Javascript (thus simply downloading the HTML gives you a boring page)

The redirect happens because of:

```
<body onload="document.acsForm.submit();">
```

..which submits the following form:

```
<form name="acsForm"
action="https://www.searspartsdirect.com/partsdirect/j_acegi_cas_security_check?ssonofail=true" 
method="post">
```

If you just try and grab the page which the browser is redirected to, you get a blank page, so I would guess you need to perform a POST request to the "action" URL, and presumably store a cookie it sets.

In the POST data, you probably need to include values for the following fields:

```
<textarea rows=10 cols=80 name="logonPassword"></textarea>
<textarea rows=10 cols=80 name="loginId"></textarea>
<textarea rows=10 cols=80 name="screenName"></textarea>
<textarea rows=10 cols=80 name="errorCode"></textarea>
```

..which would be something like `{'logonPassword': '', 'loginId': '', ...}`, which is serialised and passed as POST-data in your request

Then with the cookie, you can make a request to `http://www.searspartsdirect.com/partsdirect/index.action` or similar and your BeautifulSoup code should work as expected..

[mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) might make this all a bit simpler - the example on the homepage is basically what you want

Comment: Can u give me an example for the script from the site u have mentioned

Comment: Also i get the message mechanize._response.httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 403: request disallowed by robots.txt when i do br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("http://www.searspartsdirect.com/")

Comment: @Rajeev `br.set_handle_robots(False)`

Comment: Now i get the foloowing error   response1 = br.follow_link()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mechanize-0.2.5-py2.6.egg/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 569, in follow_link
    return self.open(self.click_link(link, **kwds))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mechanize-0.2.5-py2.6.egg/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 553, in click_link
    link = self.find_link(**kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mechanize-0.2.5-py2.6.egg/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 620, in find_link
    raise LinkNotFoundError()
mechanize._mechanize.LinkNotFoundError

Comment: @Rajeev not sure - maybe worth a separate SO question for that..?